# MVC SQL invalid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code in my MVC Index function.  It is called from a search page that allows the user to search for various string values:

```
public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string YearString,string MonthString,string BudgetTypeString,string DescriptionString)
{
        ViewBag.BudgetTypeSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "BudgetType_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.MonthSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "Month_desc" : "Month";
        ViewBag.YearSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "Year_desc" : "Year"; // 12-24-2014 JR added
        ViewBag.DescriptionSortParm = sortOrder == "Description" ? "Description_desc" : "Description";
        var budg = from s in db.budgets
                   select s; 
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(YearString) || 
            !String.IsNullOrEmpty(MonthString) || 
            !String.IsNullOrEmpty(BudgetTypeString) || 
            !String.IsNullOrEmpty(DescriptionString))
        {
            budg = budg.Where(s => s.BudgetType.ToUpper().Contains(BudgetTypeString.ToUpper()) || 
                String.IsNullOrEmpty(BudgetTypeString) || s.Description.ToUpper().Contains(DescriptionString.ToUpper()) || 
                String.IsNullOrEmpty(DescriptionString) || 
                s.Month.ToUpper().Contains(MonthString.ToUpper()) || 
                String.IsNullOrEmpty(MonthString) || 
                s.Year.ToUpper().Contains(YearString.ToUpper()) ||
                String.IsNullOrEmpty(YearString));
            budg = budg.OrderBy(s => s.BudgetType);
           return View(db.budgets.ToList());
       }

}
```

Here is the actual SQL that is converted from the above code:

```
budg    {SELECT 
[Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
[Extent1].[BudgetType] AS [BudgetType], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[Amount] AS [Amount], 
[Extent1].[Month] AS [Month], 
[Extent1].[Year] AS [Year], 
[Extent1].[DateStamp] AS [DateStamp]
FROM [dbo].[budget] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (( CAST(CHARINDEX(UPPER(@p__linq__0), 
UPPER([Extent1].[BudgetType])) AS int)) > 0) OR 
(( CAST(CHARINDEX(UPPER(@p__linq__1), UPPER([Extent1].[Description])) AS int)) > 0) OR
(( CAST(CHARINDEX(UPPER(@p__linq__2), UPPER([Extent1].[Month])) AS int)) > 0) OR
(( CAST(CHARINDEX(UPPER(@p__linq__3), UPPER([Extent1].[Year])) AS int)) > 0)}
```

Does anyone know why my strings are incorrectly being converted into integers and how to correct it so the search strings on my search page work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at just one of the Cast statements:

```
( CAST(CHARINDEX(UPPER(@p__linq__1), UPPER([Extent1].[Description])) AS int)) > 0)
```

Take a look at the inner statement. It's actually getting the CharIndex of one string in the other. Basically, does "Description" contain @p__linq__1. CharIndex returns 0 if if the first expression is not found in the other. **The result of CharIndex is what is being Cast as int**, and then compared to see if it is greater than 0. Which is exactly what you asked it to do when you use .Contains